# footer color displaying problem in website

Tags: html, css, web

I have a problem what displaying footers in website , i use css for background colors or etc. and each footer referred by same css file. Despite them referred by same css block, subpages displaying right form of footer but home page does not display the right form of the footer. Is there anyone have an idea about the solution?

[image: Home Page / Wrong Form]
[image: Subpages / True Form]

Comment: Could you please show us the code you've used/tried so far?

Comment: What do you think we are? Wizards?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve]. We can not diagnose your problem, if all you show us are screenshots, and not a single bit of actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a css block related to footer but i think our issue about html codes.

```
#site-footer .wrapper{
    padding                 : 0 40px;
}
#site-footer .footer-top{
    padding                 : 40px 0;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-logo{
    margin                  : -40px 20px 0 0;
    float                   : left;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-menu{
    margin-bottom           : 30px;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-menu ul li{
    margin-left             : 10px;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-menu ul li a{
    display                 : inline-block;
    height                  : 30px;
    line-height             : 30px;
    font-size               : 11px;
    letter-spacing          : 2px;
    font-weight             : 600;
    position                : relative;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-menu ul li a:after{
    content                 : "";
    width                   : 0;
    height                  : 2px;
    position                : absolute;
    left                    : 0;
    bottom                  : 0;
    background-color        : #d1d1d1;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-menu ul li:hover a:after{
    width                   : 50%;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-menu ul li:first-child{
    margin-left             : 0;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter{
    position                : relative;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter button,
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter input[type="text"]{
    display                 : inline-block;
    height                  : 40px;
    font-size               : 13px;
    border                  : 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    background-color        : #cacaca;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter button{
    width                   : 40px;
    position                : absolute;
    top                     : 0;
    right                   : 0;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter input[type="text"]{
    width                   : 240px;
    padding                 : 10px 50px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow      : 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(218, 218, 218, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow         : 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(218, 218, 218, 1);
    box-shadow              : 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(218, 218, 218, 1);
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter button:hover,
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter button:focus{
    outline                 : none;
    background-color        : #c1c1c1;
}
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter input[type="text"]:hover,
#site-footer .footer-top .top-newsletter input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline                 : none;
    background-color        : #e8e8e8;
}
#site-footer .footer-middle,
#site-footer .footer-bottom{
    padding                 : 20px 0;
}
#site-footer .footer-middle{
    border-top              : 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom           : 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

I can't show the html code because it goes beyond the character limit, so you can check our html structure on our website source :

http://www.nsocialtr.com/insaat-sanal-gerceklik-vr-360-video.html

http://www.nsocialtr.com/index.html